# How to set indent size in ACE editor

Tags: javascript, indentation, ace-editor

I created an ACE editor instance using the following code:

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
```

```css
#editor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.9/ace.js"></script>

<div id="editor">function foo (x) {
    return 2 * x;
}

function bar (y) {
    return foo(y) / 2;
}

console.log(bar(2) + foo(3));</div>
```

I want to control the indent size (especially when pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> key).  How can I do that?

I searched in the API reference but I couldn't find the solution...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can use `setOption("tabSize", 8)` or similar setOptions function shown bellow

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.session.setOptions({
    mode: "ace/mode/javascript",
    tabSize: 8,
    useSoftTabs: true
});
```

```css
#editor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.9/ace.js">
</script>

<div id="editor">function foo (x) {
    return 2 * x;
}</div>
```